# Do Kryptonians wear diapers?

Tags: dc, superman

In both *Superman* and *Man of Steel*, Kal-El arrives on earth *au natural*.

[image: Please put some pants on, Superboy]
[image: Please put some pants on, Superbaby]

The first version is possibly old enough to be potty-trained, but the second certainly isn't.

In the comics, do baby Kryptonians wear diapers? And if not, is it revealed how they "stay clean," so to speak?

Answer (score 5):

### Probably

Well, in many versions of Superman's origin story, he is wrapped in a blanket, thus obscuring whether he is wearing a diaper or not. This is from Secret Origins #1:

[image]

He could be naked, or he could having on a Kryptonian diaper. Of course, even if he is not wearing a diaper, Kryptonian babies might still *normally* wear diapers.

On the other hand, the cover of this comic shows Superbaby, strapped in a rocket and ready to go to Earth, wearing something that looks a lot like a red Kryptonian diaper.

[image]

(Yes, I am saying that Superman's costume is partly made of his childhood diaper).

So I'd say they probably do (at least according to one version of Superman's origin story).

As for ideas of what Kryptonians might do *without* diapers, [this thread discusses it](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=662259). Many people today do perfectly fine without diapers.

A caretaker can try to be attentive to the baby's cues, so as to know when to take it to a toilet or something similar. Babies can apparently also be trained to defecate on command. Or they can be put in a open area where messes are easy to clean.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if the adult Superman ever needs to take a bathroom break.

Comment: @HowardMiller hmm, it probably... _depends_ ;)

Comment: The question is more a.) Does he do that on comand as stated in the answer?  (couldn't resist) or b.) What becomes of the toilet afterwards (or the earth diaper.....for real if everything about him is as powerful as his physical strength....)

Comment: Maybe his clinkers are compressed into neutronium.

Comment: Heh, this honestly raises the possibility that an unknowing Superman modelled his costume on his baby outfit including nappy. Nice.